# Tool to manage all drivers

Tags: windows, device-driver

I would like a tool that helps manage drivers and not for just one type of hardware.  Nvidia's program, for example, works fine, it prompts you, downloads and installs for you...for GPU drivers.  I am looking for a program that can manage more:

- Identify available bios updates
- Windows updates
- Hardware drivers (RAM, GPU, Sound etc)
- Built in download and installation manager

An added bonus would be (This is likely completely unrealistic) a program that manages both hardware drivers and software patches.

Comment: Download.com has one but since they've filled all their hosted installers with adware I've become rather anti download.com and wouldn't recommend it without a caveat of strongly read the EULA (which I haven't in years) and be aware of privacy risks there.

Comment: You could probably use DriverMax & Ninite for hardware drivers & software patches respectively, but considering the sheer amount of hardware available, I'm not sure you'd get that can do all

Comment: Related: [Detect my hardware and install matching drivers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7588/46).

Answer (score 1):

- [Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/)
- [Dumo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?dumo) (**D**rivers **U**pdate **Mo**nitor; get the lite versions others are loaded with lame ware)
- [Sumo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) (**S**oftware **U**pdate **Mo**nitor; get the lite versions others are loaded with lame ware)
- [SlimDrivers](https://www.slimwareutilities.com/slimdrivers.php) (Make sure you **uncheck MyBackup** during install)
- [DriverUpdate](https://www.slimwareutilities.com/community/info.php?id=463&type=software) (from company that does SlimDrivers) but it sometimes conflicts with windows update.

The only thing these programs don't offer is BIOS updating.